# ng-if with formName attribute in or condition

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to hide or show my radio button using ng-if condition. Based on the formName return values.

```
  <input type="radio" class="control-label" name="reportTypeRadios"
                        ng-value="reportType" ng-if="formName != 'DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY' || formName != 'DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY'"
                        ng-model="$parent.reportTypeRadio" ng-change="propertyRadioChanged(reportTypeRadio)">
                    {{reportType.reportTypeLabel}} </input>
```

But I am seeing the radio button in both forms. For some reason the ng-if condition does not work. Can someone suggest me what is wrong ?

Comment: well if the formName is DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY, then it will not be DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY, and the ng-if will be true. the same the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

```
formName != 'DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY' || formName != 'DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY'
```

This will always evaluate to true... Logically speaking:

- If your formName is DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY then your expression is going to be: (First part)false || (second part)true == true
- If your formName is DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY then your expression is going to be: true || false == true
- If your formName is something else then your expression is going to be: true || true == true

I suspect that you wanted to write

```
formName == 'DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY' || formName == 'DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY'
```

so that you will only have the radio button showing up on those two forms that are named DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY and DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY, and nowhere else. Anyway, you should rework your condition to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The condition as in your code will always evaluate to true since formName can't be equal to both 'DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY' and 'DELETEREPORTTYPESENTITY' at the same time.
Only way ng-if gets false is if both sides of || equate to false which can never happen.

I believe what you want to achieve here could be done by just one equality i.e.

```
ng-if="formName=='DELETEREPORTTYPEENTITY'"
```